# Another RegEX question about matching and ignoring spaces

Tags: regex

I've already spent hours investiging via google without any luck. I'm familar with RegEx, but by no means an expert.

What I need to do is to take the string 'PAB 123 456' and return the token 'AB123456'.

**Background:**
I have an application which matches products via barcodes/QR codes. The app reads two codes and tries to work out if they are the same. This is a quality control type application and is written in .net

What it does is to use two RegExs, the first match from each RegEx is compared. If they are the same ... success! There are quite a few of these RegEx pairs to match different combinations and the application just tries each pair in turn.

So, using a regex like '(?<=P)([0-9A-Z]+)' on a string like 'PAB123456' this matches and returns 'AB123456' as its first token.

Using a second regex '(?<= P)([0-9A-Z]+)' on a string like '[)-071J 2P 1T PAB123456' matches and returns 'AB123456'

Thus both matched strings are the same.. success.

However a case has turned up which is causing me problems. I need to remove spaces before executing the matching regex.

**The problem:**
I need to take 'PAB 123 456' and return the token 'AB123456'. To do this I need to remove spaces on everything after the ^P, matching [0-9A-Z] after the removal.

I believe there may be another case where I have text like '[)-071J 2P 1T PAB-123-456' where I have to search for ' P' and then remove dashes, then match on what follows.

**What failed:** 
Just matching [0-9A-Z]space[0-9A-Z]space[0-9A-Z]space will not work as the first token it returns will include the spaces. I tried doing lookahead and deleting the spaces, but couldn't get the syntax right, I also tried working out a syntax for match and delete for spaces, but again couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: Another answer is that it is impossible to match and skip some chars within one match operation. Either replace (like `.*([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{3}) ([0-9]{3}).*` with `\1\2\3`) or match and then delete space as a post-processing step. No lookarounds will help you.

Comment: I don't think you need regex for that, just replace all the space with empty char ( `''`)  and remove the first character.

Comment: I thought it was possible to combine both match and skip/replace, which is why I asked the question. If not then its back to visual studio to knock out a new version of the application. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
P(AB)[ -]*(\d+)[ -]*(\d+)
```

and then reference `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

https://regexr.com/4n4ma

Comment: This relies on joining the three results, so will require recoding, which is what I wanted to avoid... but it looks like we're going to have to do. Adding a replace regex to the function will solve the problem... I think.